# 24Hour DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I currently have the standard `Datetime` using `AM`/`PM`. I wish to have 24H Display. Searching the web gave me alot of options with `String.Format()` option.

Problem is that this creates a string object to display the date. I need to use a `datetime` object because it is used in a table and the date column must be able to be sorted (asc/desc). The table is of a `GridView` Object.

**Code Example**

Currently the code shows the date as follows 8/21/2009 11:28:36 AM. I a perfect situation it would show as 11:28:36 21/8/2009. I know i can get that result with the following code.

```
date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Problem is that this is a string. The string get's placed into the table and if i sort the date column it will first sort on day instead of year. 
showing the followin descending column.

```
21/8/2009 11:28:36
20/1/2013 15:55:23
```

To correctly be able to sort the column the inserted objecttype should be DateTime. the object type is forced by the following code.

```
dateTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)));
```

Comment: An example would be nice or a piece of code..

Comment: You should override the display function in a grid's cell to display the data in a desired way.

Comment: Sorting and displaying values are two different things.

Comment: Are you using data binding?

Comment: How would you display the DateTime object with a string format ?? You need a string. As far as your GridView column is concerned you have to specify the DateTime Format for 24 Hrs time.

Comment: A `DateTime` has no format. It's just a point in time (plus a few timezone related flags). So saying a `DateTime` uses AM/PM or 24h is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1001482.aspx/1) you can use a boundfield like so:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Your_Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

You can then simply use this format string:

```
"HH:mm"
```

Where capital H renders the 24-hour time, as opposed to a small h which would render a 12-hour time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DataFormatString` property of `BoundField` in GridView